# Booting Kali-Linux with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux

So I do not want to dual boot. I have the kali-Linux.iso on a USB and I'm trying to figure out how to boot from the USB when I first turn my PC on. Also, if I boot from the USB when I turn my windows on, will this mess up my Windows 10 on my laptop? Or will it just boot windows 10 and my normal PC if the USB is not installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the BIOS immediately after the splash screen disappears when the computer is booting, and change the boot order settings so that USB-HDD is the first item in the boot order and the hard drive with Windows 10 is either the second or third item in the boot order, then save and exit the BIOS setup utility. The computer will try to boot from the USB drive if it is inserted, otherwise it will continue and boot Windows 10 from the hard drive.

If you boot Windows 10 when Kali Linux is running from the USB drive, you may damage your Kali Linux installation, because your computer cannot run two operating systems at the same time on the same physical machine. Your computer *can* run two operating systems at the same time if one of the operating systems is running inside a virtual machine. In your case, that would probably be Kali Linux running in the virtual machine, so that Windows 10 can use all the drivers for your computer's hardware that you have already installed in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your USB into your Computer and switch it on.

As it boots up hold the Del key on your keyboard to access the BIOS menu (This might be different depending on your motherboard manufacturer, try f10 or f2).

Next go to advanced BIOS features and change the boot order of you system so that USB is at the top of the menu. Save and exit. Now your computer will boot from a USB if it is plugged in.

Alternatively if you want to just do it as a one off press f11 or f12 while booting your computer to access the boot menu and choose a boot device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BIOS/UEFI key during POST for 'one time boot menu'.  Both the key and the name are BIOS/UEFI specific.  For example, with Dell systems, it's called "One Time Boot Menu" and the key is F12.  Once there choose the option that represents your USB device.

Modifying the boot order in the BIOS/UEFI is technically possible as well.  This process is also accessed through a key during POST.  It is also specific to your hardware.  There may be a settings option on the one time boot menu.  For (recent) Dell systems, it is on the one time boot menu, or F2 during POST.

For security reasons, I advise against permanently setting USB (or any other boot method) to boot before your hard drive.  I also advise putting passwords on the one time boot option, and the bios as a whole.

Booting to one operating system does not directly affect the other operating systems on a machine.  However, if you modify the files in the offline system, it may damage that system.